# Karate multi part file upload getting error from Mulesoft

Tags: karate

Mulesoft is rejected a file upload saying:
"Unable to get name from form-data"
According to this link: [MuleSoft Support](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Unable-to-get-name-from-form-data) they suggest naming convention of
following:  Content-Disposition, instead of what is being sent as content-disposition.

Feature:

```
        Given url 'https:someurlpath'
        And header Authorization = 'Basic ' + 'feefff'
        And header Content-Type = 'multipart/form-data'
        And header Accept-Encoding = 'gzip, deflate, br'
        And multipart field  callingApplicationName = 'Karate'
        And multipart file  binaryContent =  { read: 'response.tif', filename: 'response.tif', contentType: 'image/tiff' }
        And multipart field  properties = '[{"displayName":"SR Number","value":["1234","12345"]},{"displayName":"Document Type","value":"CLAI"},{"displayName":"Ingestion Source","value":"FILENETTOOLS"},{"displayName":"Received Date","value":"2022-01-14T00:52:50.837650Z"},{"displayName":"Pages","value":"0"}]'
        When method Post
        Then status 200
        And print response
        And match response.status == 'ACTIVE'
```

Here is the request:

```
1 > POST https://api.maha.com/documents-process-api/v1/documentC/specialR/documents/
1 > Authorization: Basic foooooooobooooooo
1 > Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=231ef49a739286f9
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
1 > Content-Length: 214420
1 > Host: api.maha.com
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/14.0.2)

content-disposition: form-data; name="callingApplicationName"; filename=""
content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 6
Completed: true
IsInMemory: true

Mixed: content-disposition: form-data; name="binaryContent"; filename="response.tif"
content-type: image/tiff; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 213642
Completed: true
IsInMemory: false
RealFile: /Users/req/workspace/hlx/sasquatch-automated-tests/src/test/groovy/com/maha/gpa/document/storage/service/response.tif DefaultDeleteAfter: true

content-disposition: form-data; name="properties"; filename=""
content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 278
Completed: true
IsInMemory: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a known issue with a workaround, refer this thread please: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1647

Meanwhile you are most welcome to contribute code to Karate to fix this :)